# Is it possible to view all changes made on a Git feature branch in Azure Devops?

Tags: git, azure-devops

Azure DevOps offers the overview of changes made in a branch when a PR is created. However, sometimes I'd like to have access to that overview when viewing a branch without the need to create a PR (or check out the branch locally). In the 'branches' section it's possible to view the changes on per commit basis, but the overview of all changes seems to be missing.

Is it possible to have this kind of overview of changes made in one branch in Azure DevOps without creating a PR?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the branch compare functionality.  In the list of branches, click the overflow ellipses on your feature branch and select compare branches.

[image: Branch compare in overflow menu]

Azure DevOps will diff your branch with the default branch which is changeable if necessary.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Click the Files tab to see the changed files with added and removed lines indicated.